# Simple strategy pattern returns unwanted echo output

Tags: php, strategy-pattern

when I run the script

```
<?php

interface IBrakeBehaviour {
    public function brake();
}

class Brake implements IBrakeBehaviour {
    public function brake() {
        echo "Simple Brake applied.";
    }
}

class BrakeWithABS implements IBrakeBehaviour {
    public function brake() {
        echo "Brake with ABS applied.";
    }
}

class Car {
    private $_brakeBehavior;

    public function __construct(IBrakeBehaviour $brakeBehavior)
    {
        $this->_brakeBehavior = $brakeBehavior;
    }

    public function brake() {
        $this->_brakeBehavior->brake();
    }
}

$bmw = new Car(new Brake());
$audi = new Car(new BrakeWithABS());
```

it automatically echos "Simple Brake applied." But that message should appear when I execute

```
$bmw->brake(); or $audi->brake();
```

and not before.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Herbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can both use the `__construct` and, if you wish, name the constructor the same as the class (not 100% sure if this applies to all versions).
So the problem you are experiencing is that your `Brake` class implements a constructor instead of the method you think it implements (`brake`).

Now, one could think that there would be a difference between `Brake()` and `brake()`, but no. In php, method/function names are case insensitive, so they are the same...

How to bypass this issue?
If you implement the constructor as `__construct` **before** implementing the `brake` function, it should work, ie:

```
class Brake {
  public function __construct() {} // First
  public function Brake() {}       // Then this
}
```

Else you might get a `Redefining already defined constructor` error.

Comment: Awesome. Your suggestion worked. Many thanks for the additional support.